# How to hide a form when someone submits and replace it with another text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm google apps script to send the entered information to my email. But right now it opens a new page which shows

```
{"result":"success","data":"{\"emailadd\":[\"emailhere\"]}"}
```

I got the script from here but it does not work all properly:
https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server

If i add form-submission-handler.js from the link above, the javascript hides the form and replaces it with a text but does not actually send me an email

Here is my form right now:

```
<form style="margin:5px" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxtEjbRqMkB-H-qCSClo1QfCKwOK3LT_b_6y11x_VaINIdmforY/exec">

        <input type="text" id="email" type="email" name="emailadd" value="" required placeholder="Email" style="color:#2d2d2d; margin-right:1em;">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning ">
    </form>
```

How do i hide the entire form and replace it some text whenever someone clicks the submit button while still executing the form's action

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id to your form tag like this :

< form id="Something">

And then you can hide your form on submit button :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('Something').hide(0).fadeIn(1000);
$('form.registerButton').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();// will stop the form being submited...
    $(this).hide(1000);
    // do changes here...
    $( "Something" ).replaceWith( "<form>New form</form>" );
    return false;
});
});
```

for more help and undrestanding better ,look at:

[How to replace HTML code with Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Hope this will help